# What is the difference between 높임말 and 존댓말?

Tags: grammar, meaning

When it comes to honorifics in Korean, I see two words: 높임말 and 존댓말. Are these two words different or the same?

Comment: They are same. 존대 is a Sino-Korean word which has the same meaning of 높임.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comment, they are the same.
Naver Korean dictionary gives the exact same explanation for the two words.